# Is it valid to define an object without any sub-properties in OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0)?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

Is the following OpenAPI definintion valid?

```json
        "settings": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "Json formatted public settings for the extension."
        },
```

It's defined as `object` but has no sub-properties.

Comment: in swagger you should have objects that are passed as input or output of your API. Are you using `settings` object there? If yes, it should has som properties, which user pass/gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this definition is valid and means that `settings` is a free-form object, that is, it can have arbitrary properties or be an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OWASP security risk

https://docs.42crunch.com/latest/content/oasv3/datavalidation/schema/v3-schema-response-object-without-properties.htm