# How to define "interface" as a datatype in open API?

Tags: go, interface, openapi, go-gin, api-doc

In my **golang** project, I have a structure that contains this field:

```
type hook struct {
   Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

How to represent this **Data** field in Open API Spec?

Comment: Is this useful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514763/is-it-valid-to-define-an-object-without-any-sub-properties-in-openapi-2-0-swagg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use the absolutely free form type in the specification, I think, but if you want to do so, use the `{}` form of definition:

```
data: {}
```

Also you can add a `null` value to the allowed:

```
data:
  nullable: true
```

See the "Any Type" section of the types documentation: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/